# vim, open file with vertical split in different lines

Tags: vim

In vim, you can open a file with the cursor in particular line

Example: open file.txt with the cursor over the line 10

```
vim file.txt +10
```

With -O you can open the same file with vertical split

```
vim -O file.txt file.txt
```

How can I open the same file with a vertical split and with the cursor over specific lines?

something like

```
vim -O file.txt +10 file.txt +20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use following command `vim +20 file.txt +"vsplit +10 file.txt"`

Switch window with CTRL+w l (CTRL+w h)